# What is that round antenna(?) on the bottom of a Piper Comanche?

Tags: feature-identification, antenna, piper-pa-24

Does anyone recognize this round object under the belly of a PA-24?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

From a Comanche parts catalog, it's the ADF loop antenna (item 45) minus the aero cover (30):

> [image]
> http://www.aeroelectric.com/Reference_Docs/Piper/pa-24-180-250-260-400_pcv1998.pdf

Comment: Thanks, especially for the link. I think I'll be referring to that a lot.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably the ADF loop antenna. To read properly, it must be installed so the little airplane's nose points in the direction of flight.

Comment: I dont have the long sense antenna (at least not on the exterior) which makes sense, since I dont have an operable ADF any longer. And the little airplane is facing the right way.